# How to set title to a powerpoint slide using win32com client

Tags: python, powerpoint, win32com, python-pptx

Could anyone please help me in setting a title to a powerpoint slide using win32com library in Python. The following is the code. I have used the slide layout 11 which denotes Title only

```
import openpyxl as op
import pptx
import os
import win32com.client

import smtplib

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT')
path= r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT\Summary2.xlsx'
wb = op.load_workbook(path)
ExcelApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = False
workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.open(r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT\Summary2.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Summary")
excelrange = worksheet.Range("A2:R24")

PptApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
PptApp.Visible = True
z= excelrange.Copy()
PPtPresentation = PptApp.Presentations.Open(r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT\PBC Performance Update.pptx')
pptSlide = PPtPresentation.Slides.Add(1,11)
#pptSlide.Title.Characters.Text ='Metrics'

#title = pptSlide.Shapes.Title
#title.Text ='Metrics Summary'
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(z)
PPtPresentation.Save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a small syntax issue:

```
PptApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
PptApp.Visible = True
z= excelrange.Copy()
PPtPresentation = PptApp.Presentations.Open(r'C:\Users\aju.mathew.thomas\Desktop\PBC\Pepsi\PBC\Performance Reports\2019\PPT\PBC Performance Update.pptx')
pptSlide = PPtPresentation.Slides.Add(1,11)
title = pptSlide.Shapes.Title
title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = 'My title here'
```